# ggplot2 shared axis for one data set

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to have two axis using different scales/units, both matching one single dataset. The problem is that the two axis are non-monotonic. An example is shown below:

```
library(ggplot2)
d <- data.frame(
  time = c(1:10),
  signal1 = seq(10, 100, by=10),
  signal2 = c(10,11,13,14.2, 14.5, 16, 18, 18.2,19.6, 20)
)

axis.transform <- approxfun(d$signal1, d$signal2)

ggplot(d, aes(x=time, y=signal1)) + geom_point() +

scale_y_continuous(
  "signal 1", 
  sec.axis = sec_axis(~axis.transform(.), name = "signal 2")
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot with 2 y axes, one y axis on the left, and another y axis on the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another-y-axis-on-the-right)

Comment: And what is the issue with the solution you found?

Comment: I clarified the question. The issue is that this solution only works with monotonic functions, which is not my case.

Comment: @JohnBee then the example graph is not a good example...

Comment: @snoram you are right. I'm reformulating the question with a more representative example

Comment: I'm not sure that understand your idea behind the code completely. But wouldn't be helpful  to use `scales::rescale()` instead of `approxfun()` ?